# How to set deflater to HUFFMAN_ONLY in GZIPOutputstream

Tags: java, gzip, huffman-code, deflate

Hi i am just wondering is it possible to set the deflater used in gzip output stream to use HUFFMAN_ONLY, i have it working with my own deflate method.

```
public static byte[] deflate(byte[] data) throws IOException {  
   Deflater deflater = new Deflater();  
   deflater.setInput(data);  
   ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);   
   deflater.finish();
   deflater.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION); //*****THESE 2 LINES HERE
   deflater.setStrategy(Deflater.HUFFMAN_ONLY); // *******
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];   
   while (!deflater.finished()) {  
    int count = deflater.deflate(buffer); // returns the generated code... index  
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);   
   }  
   outputStream.close();  
   byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();  
   return output;  
  }
```

so basically i want to know how to set the deflater used in my gzip method to the same as the deflater above when i use the lines:

```
   deflater.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
   deflater.setStrategy(Deflater.HUFFMAN_ONLY);
```

this is my gzip method:

```
//GZIP Compression method
public static byte[] compress(String data) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
    gzip.write(data.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    return compressed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can just use `Deflater` with `nowrap` set to true, and write your own gzip header and trailer.

Comment: Hi would you have an example of this i am still quite new to this, i am basically going to be using gzip for compressing mqtt message payloads. thanks for the reply anyway

Comment: You can read RFC 1952 for the layout of the gzip header and trailer. It is quite easy to generate. You can just use a fixed 10-byte gzip header, and compute the uncompressed length and CRC-32 to construct the trailer.